# Programatically creating and joining Hyperledger Fabric channels

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric

The Hyperledger Fabric SDK allows for the programmatic creation of channels.

I am wondering about how this makes sense in a realistic blockchain network with more than one organization?

At least all peers which should join that channel need some way to check that joining the channel and creating the channel is in their sense.

Is there a way to do the creation and joining in a comfortable and secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sufficient signatures to Fabric's liking in order to create a channel anyway.
Joining the channel can be done after inspection of the genesis block at each organization.

The programmatic ability to create and join channel is that you or anyone else could create a "management application" that collaborates between the organizations, collects signatures, presents the content of the genesis block in a nice way, etc. etc.

It's only a tool. What you do with it (if you use at all) is your choice.